# Reconstruction error drops for an anomaly?

Tags: conv-neural-network, keras, autoencoders, feature-engineering

I have a convolutional Autoencoder being used as an anomaly detector, it works well. Today however I trained it on a new training/test data set and the anomalies were exposed as a drop in reconstruction error.? In all other data sets I've been using the Reconstruction Error increased when an anomaly was found.
I'm looking for an explanation for why the Reconstruction Error would drop when an Anomaly was discovered, as this does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the anomalies are just easily constructed. For example if a nonanomalous input is a picture of a cat, then an anomalous input might be just a grey blob. Yet it's much easier to reconstruct a blob than a detailed image of a cat.